# Вывод гистограмм с нормальным распределением. matplotlib seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

все разбираюсь со вчерашним вопросом. в первой части кода я смог вывести гистограмму с линией нормального распределения после нормирования данных. но графики обеих параметров вывелись в один график. как вывести их в отдельные графики? Вчера написали что с помощью subplot гистограммы вывести получилось но без линий нормальных распределений. Помогите с этим разобраться пожалуйста)

```
listParam = ['SalePrice', 'GrLivArea']
for param in listParam:
    (mu, sigma) = norm.fit(train[param])
    print( '\n mu = {:.2f} and sigma = {:.2f}\n'.format(mu, sigma))
    train[param] = np.log1p(train[param])
   (mu, sigma) = norm.fit(train[param])
    print( '\n mu = {:.2f} and sigma = {:.2f}\n'.format(mu, sigma))


for param in listParam:    
    sns.distplot(train[param], fit=norm)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, len(listParam),figsize=(4*len(listParam), 4))
fig.suptitle('Нормированные значения')

ax1.hist(train['SalePrice'], bins=20, density=True)
ax1.plot()
ax2.hist(train['GrLivArea'],bins=20, density=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как-то так должно получиться, такой же `subplot`, как у вас дальше:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(listParam),figsize=(4*len(listParam), 4))
for i,param in enumerate(listParam):    
    sns.distplot(train[param], fit=norm, ax=ax[i])
```

Можно и в один `subplot` 2x2 все четыре графика поместить, это как угодно.

Comment: Идельно) Огромное спасибо